# Text Report into Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been given the following text report:

```
"Date: DD/MM/YYYY Access Report            Page:      1"  
"Time: HH:MM Access Report                             "  
"                                                      "  
"Group :   $All *Always        SubGroup: $Standard     "        
"                                                      "  
"Door Name--------                                     "  
"02 Main Entrance                                      "  
"05 Stock Room                                         "  
"                                                      "  
"Group:    John Doe *Always    Subgroup: $Standard     "  
"                                                      "  
"Door Name--------                                     "  
"04 UPS ROOM                                           "  
"02 Main Entrance                                      "  
"                                                      "  
"Group: Afternoon 3:30 - 4:30  Subgroup: $Standard     "  
"12 Main Door                                          "  
"05 Stock Door                                         "  
"                                                      "  
"Date: DD/MM/YYYY Access Report            Page:      2"  
"Time: HH:MM Access Report                             "
```

---

I am trying to create a table from this report as such:

```
         "Main Entrance"  "Stock Room"  "UPS Room"  "Main Door"  "Stock Door"
John Doe       Yes             Null/No    Yes         No/Null       No/Null 
Afternoon      No/Null         No/Null    No/Null      Yes             Yes
```

I don't have a list of all the doors that are possible and i don't have a list of all the possible groups.

I want to have a table created from this report. Or organize the report into a more functional way; an array with the name of the group (i.e: John Doe) and its elements are the doors he can access.

I don't know where to start or how to approach this. I was considering using a Macro-VBA in excel as the file was given to me as an excel file with the text pasted into one column and rows are line breakers.

Comment: Interesting problem, however SO might not be the best place to start if you don't know where to begin.  We are really more for helping you out once you get going and run into an issue...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @chancea...have a look at [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html) this is an example of a file reader in VBA and should put you on the right track.